# fatal error: 'arrayobject.h' file not found when using pyenv

Tags: python, numpy, pipenv, pyenv

I am trying to use the following package: https://github.com/vBaiCai/python-pesq and I am also using `Pipenv` and `pyenv`.  I have installed `3.6-dev` with `pyenv` and am using that with `pipenv --python ~/.pyenv/versions/3.6-dev/bin/python3`.

When I do `pipenv install pypesq`, I get a ton of errors, including:

```
    file numpy.py (for module numpy) not found
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

    running build_ext
    building 'pesq_core' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.6/pypesq
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I/Users/shamoon/.pyenv/versions/3.6-dev/include/python3.6m -I/Users/shamoon/.pyenv/versions/3.6-dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c pypesq/pesq.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.6/pypesq/pesq.o
    pypesq/pesq.c:2:10: fatal error: 'arrayobject.h' file not found
    #include "arrayobject.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

I am on OS X if that matters. Any help.

Comment: it tries to compile code in C/C++ but it needs .h files for this - I found that `'arrayobject.h'` can be part of module `numpy` so you need its source code or at least its files .h. Or maybe if you install module `numpy` then it will have theses files.

Comment: I have `numpy` in my `Pipfile` already

Comment: error shows that it can't find `numpy` so maybe you run it with wrong Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `pyenv` to install `Python 3.6-dev` on `Linux Mint 19.2` and I found two problems during installation `pypesq`:

---

#### 1. It couldn't find `arrayobject.h` from module `numpy`

I used answer from Ubuntu forum [fatal error: numpy/arrayobject.h: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883109/fatal-error-numpy-arrayobject-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

I had to find folder with `arrayobject.h` and add it to environment variable `CFLAGS` so later `C/C++` compiler will use it to find `arrayobject.h`- ie. (directly in terminal)

```
export CFLAGS="-I /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ $CFLAGS"
```

I was installing `pypesq` for `Python 3.6-dev` but I used path to `numpy` installed in `Python 3.7` and there was no problem.

**BTW:** To find it I used shell command `locate` which is not standard command but it works much faster then `find`

---

#### 2. It couldn't find `pesq.h`

Instead of using module from `pip` server I used [code from GitHub](https://github.com/vBaiCai/python-pesq) which was updated yesterday

```
pipenv install https://github.com/vBaiCai/python-pesq/archive/master.zip
```

---

After that I could import it in `Python 3.6-dev` but I didn't test if it works correctly.

Comment: Perfect - that worked. Do I need to do the export only when doing the `Pipenv install` the first time?

Comment: yes, `export` is needed only during installation`pypesq` because it compiles C/C++ code which needs information from file `arrayobject.h` (probably to have access to `numpy` which was also created in C/C++).